# Приглушить мотор автомобиля невозможно?

Tags: значения

Может, так было раньше, но в наше время мотор автомобиля можно только выключить, т.е. заглушить.

Что имеют в виду, говоря "приглуши" мотор?

Answer (score 4):

Да, в данном случае именно это оно и означает. Причина подобного словоупотребления довольно прозрачна - моторы, а также разные прочие механизмы, работают довольно громко.

Значение это разговорное и не основное, однако же встречается довольно часто и в практически любом словаре имеется. Например, [wiki:глушить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: То есть, заглушить и приглушить мотор значит одно и то же?

Comment: @J.Doe В общем-то нет. "Заглушить" - это просто форма совершенного вида, которая выражает законченное действие. А "приглушить" имеет добавочное значение "сделать _частично_ тише", "заглушить не до конца". Но, в принципе, в разговорной речи люди иногда могут такие нюансы смешивать между собой.

Comment: Но мотор автомобиля нельзя частично или?

Comment: @J.Doe Нельзя. Поэтому "приглуши мотор" фактически будет означать то же самое, что и "заглуши", являясь при этом небольшой речевой неточностью (вполне возможно, что и намеренной).

Comment: @J.Doe ***ПРИглуши*** может означать ***временно*** *заглуши*, и звучит не так категорично, как ***ЗАглуши***, потому годится как способ смягчения императива

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка это самый подходящий мне ответ.

Comment: "Приглуши" may indeed mean a short timespan, like "приглуши на минутку". But it also can mean to decrease the power, like moving from full throttle to idle gas. Based on the idea that the more power a working device uses - the more noise it generates. So lowering noise implies lowering performance rate. Granted, the initial claim "можно только заглушить" seem very dubious to me, perhaps only true in some very narrow context.